# Zweite und dritte Person im gleichen Satz - wonach richtet sich das Verb?

Tags: verb, grammatical-person

> **This question also has an answer here (in English):**
> ["Paula und ich bin..." or "Paula und ich sind..."](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20520/1224)

---

Wenn man zwei verschiedene Personen im gleichen Satzteil beschreibt, von denen einer angesprochen wird und einer nicht, wie muß dann das Verb korrekterweise gebeugt werden?

Beispiele, wo es kein Problem ist:

> Frank und Martin *sind* meine besten Freunde. (Beides dritte Person.)
>
> Du und Martin, ihr *seid* meine besten Freunde. (Zweite und dritte Person, aber verschiedene Satzteile.)

Beispiel, wo das Problem auftaucht:

> Du und Martin *[sind|seid]* meine besten Freunde. (Zweite und dritte Person, gleicher Satzteil.)

Oder kann man solche Sätze vielleicht gar nicht sinnvoll bilden?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bei mehrteiligem Subjekt mit **2. Person und 3. Person** ist die **zweite Person Plural** zu verwenden:

> Du und Martin **seid** meine besten Freunde.

Die beiden Subjekte *du* und *Martin* können nämlich durch *ihr* zusammengefasst werden: *"Ihr seid meine besten Freunde."*

Wenn eine **1. und 2. Person** zusammen verwendet werde , muss das Verb in der **ersten Person Plural** stehen:

> Du und ich **sind** beste Freunde.

(du und ich = wir)

Wenn eine **1. Person und eine 3. Person** miteinander verbunden werden, richtet sich das Verb wieder nach der **ersten Person Plural**.

> Martin und ich sind beste Freunde.

(er + ich = wir)

---

*Ein kleine Anmerkung:* Würde im Beispiel statt *und* ein *oder* stehen, müsste man das Verb nach der Person des Subjekts richten, das dem Verb am nächsten steht:

> Du oder Martin ist mein bester Freund.

Da derartige Sätze meist etwas seltsam klingen, vermeidet man sie, indem man sie mit einem unbestimmten Pronomen umschreibt:

> Du oder Martin, einer von euch ist mein bester Freund.

Comment: Martin und Frank müssen aber viel durchmachen. Jetzt ist nur noch einer von beiden der beste Freund, und keiner weiß welcher... ;) +1 für die vollständige Antwort, die Regeln waren mir bisher nicht klar. Viele dieser Sätze würde ich trotzdem eher vermeiden, weil sie etwas seltsam klingen, insbesondere der erste, auf den sich eigentlich die Frage bezog. Außerdem kenne ich Frank nicht.

Comment: @OregonGhost Danke! Den ersten Satz empfinde ich gar nicht mal so seltsam. Ich persönlich würde wahrscheinlich die *oder-Version* nie so sagen.

Comment: Die Version mit *oder* ist vor allem inhaltlich nicht so schön ;) Beim ersten Satz würde ich die Variante "Du und Martin, *ihr* seid [...]" definitiv bevorzugen.