# "Paula und ich bin..." or "Paula und ich sind..."

Tags: grammatical-number, conjugation

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier beantwortet (auf Deutsch):**
>   [Zweite und dritte Person im gleichen Satz - wonach richtet sich das Verb?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1751/1224)

---

I am quite new to the German language. I'd like to know which of the following is correct:

1. Paula und ich sind im Café.
2. Paula und ich bin im Café.

To me, it seems that #1 should be correct. Is my understanding correct or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. #1 is correct. 
In case of just one single person you use *bin*. E.g. "Ich bin im Cafe"
If there are 2 or more persons as in your case, you use *sind*.