# Personform des Verbes bei mehreren möglichen Subjekten

Tags: verb

Ich werde nicht schlau darüber, ob es, wenn es mehrere Subjekte in einem Satz gibt, die mit "oder" getrennt sind und wenn sie verschiedene Personen haben, das Verb wiederholt sein muss oder ob man hier eine Ellipse machen kann.

> Kauft Lotte oder (kauft) Kurt das Auto?

ist korrekt und das zweite "kauft" kann weggelassen werden.

> Kaufst du oder Willy das Auto?
>   Kaufen die Brüder oder Erich oder vielleicht du das Auto?

sind vielleicht nicht korrekte Sätze, weil verschiedene Verbformen für die zwei Subjekte nötig sind.
Die Frage: Sind meine Annahmen richtig? Ich kann die Antwort nicht anderswo finden.

Comment: Relevant: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1751/15318

Comment: Legitimer Grund fürs Passiv: _Wird das Auto von den Brüdern oder Erich oder vielleicht dir gekauft?_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deine Frage behandelt ein so genanntes mehrteiliges Subjekt, eine umfangreiche Anleitung ist auf [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html) zu finden.

Somit sind alle deine Beispiele korrekt, bei der Verwendung von **oder** richtet sich der Numerus des Verbs nach dem des am nächsten stehenden Teilsubjekts:

> Kaufen die Brüder oder Erich oder vielleicht du das Auto?
>
> Kauft Erich oder die Brüder oder vielleicht du das Auto?

(Siehe [hier](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mit-23240).)

Ich glaube nicht, dass das eine Ellipse ist, aber das entzieht sich leider meiner Kenntnis.

Answer (score -3):

Mein Vorschlag:

> Wer kauft das Auto? Erich oder die Brüder oder vielleicht du?